# Find the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\sqrt [5] {x-\tan^{-1} x}}{x^{3/5}}$

Tags: limits

Find the following limit,

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\sqrt [5] {x-\tan^{-1} x}}{x^{3/5}}$$

> Observation: Both top and bottom are 0 for $\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt [5] {x-\tan^{-1} x}$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}{x^{3/5}}$. Therefore, this seems to hint that I should use the L'Hopital Rule...
>
> So I try it. $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\sqrt [5] {x-\tan^{-1} x}}{x^{3/5}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {(\frac{1}{5})({x-\tan^{-1} x})^{-4/5}(1-\frac{1}{x^2+1})}{(\frac{3}{5})x^{-2/5}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {(x)^{2/5}(1-\frac{1}{x^2+1})}{3{({x-\tan^{-1} x})^{4/5}}}$$
>
> I notice if I apply L Hopital rule again, I will get back to square one.
>
> > After that I tried several ways that included rationalizing the function, etc.

Any hints? Thanks in advance! List them as solutions. I am looking for hints only.

Comment: Note that $$\frac{\sqrt[5]{x-\tan^{-1}x}}{x^{3/5}}=\frac{\sqrt[5]{x-\tan^{-1}x}}{\sqrt[5]{x^3}}=\sqrt[5]{\frac{x-\tan^{-1}x}{x^3}},$$ and continuity lets the limit pass through the radical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hints:** (i) Forget about fifth roots for a while, study
$\dfrac{x-\tan^{-1} x}{x^3}$.

(ii) Then using L'Hospital's Rule is fine, but **look carefully** after you have applied it once.